# как создать deb из репозитария archlinux

Tags: debian, archlinux, deb

Проблема такая, требуется deb, дабы устанавливать его виртуалках и чтоб он обновлял все зависящие пакеты. 
Устанавливаем

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/ggnfs-svn.git
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/msieve.git
```

Вот исходники http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/msieve/msieve/Msieve%20v1.53/msieve153_src.tar.gz
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ggnfs/files/ggnfs-sources/0.77.1/
 А дальше что и как? Где мне просмотреть исходники? Как собрать пакет?
P.S.: Debian 9.4

Comment: Распаковать, почитать инструкции по сборке deb-пакетов в целом, инструкции по сборке этого продукта в частности (к любому уважающему себя продукту прилагаются либо они, либо `Makefile`, либо его производящая), а потом совместить их.

Comment: а вообще самое нулевое действие: вам надо определиться с тем, про что вы спрашиваете: про ggnfs или про msieve. если **и про то и про то**, то конкретику **про оба** следует удалить и переформулировать вопрос в абстрактную форму: «есть исходники, как их дебианизировать». ну и, соответственно, сразу же получить ссылку для вдумчивого изучения: https://wiki.debian.org/ru/HowToPackageForDebian

Comment: Вот нет документации...